# Getting "weighted" measures from different measure groups using date and year

Tags: ssas

Two different measure groups - Transactions and Goals
Transactions have a specific date, where as Goal is only associated with a year.
I cant tie Goal to my Date dimension since there are more than one record for a given year.

The Goals are yearly values.  There is a "Weighting" table that I have not yet turned into a dimension.  This weighting uses fractional values for each of the 12 months of the year, and add up to 1.

I need to display YTD values for both Transactions and Goals, but for the Goals, the "weighting" must be applied.

So how then, could one look at values from both Transactions and Goals measures AND filter by the year?

Answer (score 0):

While you could do this all in MDX calcs, the easiest way is to create a view in your relational database that joins the goals to the monthly weights and outputs one goal row per month with the weighting applied. You can either identify a month by tying it to the first day of the month like 20150801 or you could return both of the keys of your month attribute as two columns and then join to your date dimension at the non-leaf grain in the Dimension Usage tab of the cube designer.